# use ref in reactjs-popup trigger

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react-table component with custom column header

```
const popupRef = createRef();

    const column = [{
        Header: () =>
           <div ref={popupRef} className="eye-icon">
                <img src={icon}/>
           </div>
        fixed: "left",
        sortable: false,
        headerClassName: "table-header-class",
        className: "table-row-class",
        width: 70
    }];
```

And I have a reactjs-popup that I want to be triggered after I press on that component.

```
return (
    <div>
        <Popup
            className="popup"
            closeOnDocumentClick
            trigger={popupRef.current}
            arrow={true}
            repositionOnResize={true}
            on="click"
            position="bottom left"
        >
            <div className="popup">
               <span>popup</span>
            </div>
        </Popup>
        <div className="table">
            <ReactTableFixedColumns
                showPagination={false}
                defaultPageSize={selectedTestsLength}
                data={data}
                style={{height: "73vh"}}
                columns={column}
            />
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

It doesn't work.
Of course I can make onClick event in header's div to forcly open the popup with reactjs-popup open property - but it appears on the center of the screen and it looks like modal, so this approach is not suitable, I want it to stick to the div, to be placed in correct place.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the wrong approach here. Refs are not needed to achieve what you want.

Just simply declare the Popup inline inside the header:

```
const column = [{
    Header: () =>
       <Popup trigger={
           <div ref={popupRef} className="eye-icon">
                <img src={icon}/>
           </div>
       }>
           <div className="popup">
                <span>popup</span>
           </div>
       </Popup>
    fixed: "left",
    sortable: false,
    headerClassName: "table-header-class",
    className: "table-row-class",
    width: 70
}];
```

I don't have access to your full code so I can't tell for sure but that should give you the idea.

Comment: @ klugjo Thank you. I don't want to put popup code in the react-table's header code - if I rerender the table ( and that what I exactly do in my popup) then the popup will close. It's not good. I want to make the popup code to be in another place, but the trigger should be in the table's header

Comment: BTW There is another approach. I don't want to use open={state_param} option in popup, because it want uncontrolled popup with arrow and position in exact place. I want to avoid open parameter in popup and I want to set the trigger on header's element but outside of the react-table code.

Answer (score 0):

I just did an empty div and put trigger in it

```
        trigger={<div className="sample-trigger"></div>}

.sample-trigger {
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

In the main div I am using to trigger the popup I set the onClick to change the state of {wasPopupOpen}

```
   <Popup
        className="popup"
        closeOnDocumentClick
        open={wasEyePopupOpen}...
```

I also make some adjustmenst on popup window so it looks like inside of that div.